# PHP why won't this JSON decode

Tags: php, json

**SOLVED** - *html_entity_decode* was the solution

My JSON is not decoding. Can anyone spot my mistake?

The JSON string looks like this:

```
{"ustaAddr":"1198 Industrial Way","ustaCity":"Carmel, CA","ustaPCode":"90210"}
```

Here is the code:

```
$newShipTo = stripslashes($aTrans['new_ship_to']);
if ($newShipTo != ""){
    $arrShipToAddr = json_decode($newShipTo, TRUE);
    $buyer_addr = $arrShipToAddr['ustaAddr'];
    $buyer_city = $arrShipToAddr['ustaCity'];
    $buyer_pcode= $arrShipToAddr['ustaPCode'];
    $shipTo_addr = 'TEST' . '<p>' .$buyer_addr. '</p><p>'.$buyer_city. '</p><p>'.$buyer_pcode. '</p>' ;
}

echo $shipTo_addr;
```

**Result:**

```
TEST
```

---

I also tried this:

```
    $shipTo_addr = $arrShipToAddr['ustaAddr'] .' - '. $newShipTo;
```

**Result:**

```
- {"ustaAddr":"1198 Industrial Way","ustaCity":"Carmel, CA","ustaPCode":"90210"}
```

I also tried this:

```
    $shipTo_addr = $arrShipToAddr->ustaAddr .' - '. $newShipTo;
```

**Result:**

```
- {"ustaAddr":"1198 Industrial Way","ustaCity":"Carmel, CA","ustaPCode":"90210"}
```

Can anyone spot what I've done wrong? I can't see it...

---

**UPDATE:**

The json_decode() statement is failing, but I can't see why.

```
$shipTo_addr = (is_array($arrShipToAddr)) ? 'yes' : 'no';
```

Returns "no"

---

**Update Two:**

I hard-coded the text string (copy/pasted from the screen result from above test output!), and it worked! (Of course, that's not a solution as the JSON string is dynamically created elsewhere and retrieved from MySQL).

```
$newShipTo = '{"ustaAddr":"1198 Industrial Way One","ustaCity":"Carmel, CA Two","ustaPCode":"90210 Free"}'; 
if ($newShipTo != ""){
    $arrShipToAddr = json_decode($newShipTo, TRUE);
    $shipTo_addr = (is_array($arrShipToAddr)) ? 'yes' : 'no';
}
```

**Result:**

```
yes
```

I also tried these promising suggestions, but no joy:

```
$newShipTo = json_encode(stripslashes($aTrans['new_ship_to'])); //re-encode using PHP json_encode
```

and

```
$arrShipToAddr = json_decode(utf8_encode($newShipTo), TRUE); //force utf8
```

Comment: [Works for me](https://eval.in/280450)

Comment: @JohnConde Thanks John, helps to know that.

Comment: `var_dump($arrShipToAddr, $newShipTo)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well guys, someone over here asked if there was anything unusual about the field type in the database.

The data, as stored in the field, was html_entitied (looked like this):

```
{\&quot;ustaAddr\&quot;:\&quot;1198 Industrial Way Here\&quot;,\&quot;ustaCity\&quot;:\&quot;Carmel, CA We\&quot;,\&quot;ustaPCode\&quot;:\&quot;90210 Go\&quot;}
```

However, after using `stripslashes` and `json_decode`, the string outputted like this:

```
{"ustaAddr":"176 Industrial Drive","ustaCity":"Carmel, CA","ustaPCode":"90210"}
```

At first, I thought it was the `TEXT` field type and thought that changing to a `VARCHAR` was the solution. Nope.

Using `stripslashes` and `json_decode` wasn't enough. To solve the problem, I had to do this:

```
$newShipTo = stripslashes(html_entity_decode($aTrans['new_ship_to']));
```

So, the complete code block:

```
$newShipTo = stripslashes(html_entity_decode($aTrans['new_ship_to']));
if ($newShipTo != ""){
    $arrShipToAddr = json_decode($newShipTo, TRUE);
    $buyer_addr = $arrShipToAddr['ustaAddr'];
    $buyer_city = $arrShipToAddr['ustaCity'];
    $buyer_pcode= $arrShipToAddr['ustaPCode'];
    $shipTo_addr = '<p>' .$buyer_addr. '</p><p>'.$buyer_city. '</p><p>'.$buyer_pcode. '</p>' ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me, but you can try :

```
$arrShipToAddr = json_decode(utf8_encode($newShipTo), TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$newShipTo = '{"ustaAddr":"1198 Industrial Way","ustaCity":"Carmel, CA","ustaPCode":"90210"}';
```

which then can be decoded it into an array.

Comment: Yes, I was just about to update the question to say that I did this and it worked, but of course I cannot hard code the JSON string -- it's dynamically created elsewhere.  The question I am left with is, *Why can I copy/paste the screen output and it decodes, but the string before it gets output does not decode?"*

Comment: It won't work because you are passing JSON format in a PHP variable but instead you should pass it as a string. Could you copy the code that sets the value of $aTrans['new_ship_to'] in the first place?